# NSDateFormatter and stringFromDate

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

So, I have

```
let formatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy MM dd"
```

And then I have

```
dateLabel.text = formatter.stringFromDate(currentDate!)
```

But when I do this:

```
(lldb) po dateLabel.text
▿ Optional<String>
  - Some : "2016 01 17"

(lldb) po currentDate
▿ Optional<NSDate>
  - Some : 2016-01-18 00:00:00 +0000
```

Obivously, conversion from 2016-01-18 to string results in 2016 01 17. Any ideas?

Comment: I think the timezone is not captured, how are you creating currentDate

Comment: Yep. It might have something to do with your currentDate. try  dateLabel.text = formatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())

Comment: stringFromDate(NSDate()) is correct. Prints out Aug/4 as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to refer to UTC timezone

```
    let dateString = "2016 01 17"
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
    let s = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
    print(s)
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick and simple answer.

Comment: Happy coding @Latcie